# Making a wordpress shortcode reusable

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-shortcode

I have created a wordpress shortcode which outputs a form. The following is my shortcode

```
function testcode(){
   echo "<h1>TEST</h1>";
}
```

add_shortcode("test-code","testcode");

What i want is to be able to include the `<h1>Test</h1>` in a file such that users who want to override the shorcode can simply create a new file.

So something like

```
  function testcode(){
      //load html from a a file like templates/test.php
  }
 add_shortcode("test-code","testcode");
```

How do i proceed to make this reusable and extendable?

Comment: which users do you mean would be able to *simply create a new file*?

Comment: @gael the above code is located in a plugin and i would like for plugin users to have the capbility to override the file by simply creating a folder with the file in it.

Answer (score 1):

you can add a file parameter to the shortcodeload a separate file.

```
function testcode( $atts = [], $content = null, $tag = '' ){
     // normalize attribute keys, lowercase
     $atts = array_change_key_case((array)$atts, CASE_LOWER);

     // override default attributes with user attributes
     $atts = shortcode_atts(
        [
            'file' => 'default.php',
        ],
        $atts, 
        $tag
    );
    ob_start();

    // echo "/some/path/{$atts['file']}";
    require "/some/path/{$atts['file']}";

    $contents = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $contents;
}
add_shortcode("test-code","testcode");

echo do_shortcode( '[test-code file="sagar"] ');
```

Reference:
https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/shortcodes/shortcodes-with-parameters/
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/

Comment: Including it via     require "/some/path/{$atts['file']}";
 limits users from overriding the template. My shortcode is located in a plugin and i want users to be able to overide this in the theme later by creating a folder with a specific name and the file which should automatically override it.

Comment: @Geoff Then what you are seeking is the template override functionality similar to WooCommerce.  Then you need to implement 3 functions similar to WooCommerce, they are wc_get_template_part, wc_get_template and wc_locate_template. You can find those functions here https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/wc-core-functions.php

Comment: @Geoff Let me know if you have any problem.